# Why has a number an indexed property?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I think I still have not understood TypeScript.

I can declare

```
let x: number = 9;
```

and then access

```
let y: number = x[6]; // 6 is an example. Any index really...
```

I am from a C# background, and this looks so wrong to me. Why can I access an array position on a variable that is no array in the first place?
For C#, of course, a string is an array of chars. So if you do the above with a string in C# you'd get the 7th char. But in typescript? On a number?

I know for JavaScript this is due to the very free typing, but I had hoped the TypeScript Transpiler would deny this... it does not. Is there a good reason for this, or even a handy usage?

Comment: You should enable _noImplicitAny_ compiler option and you'll get an error

Comment: `[]` is not just for array indices. It is also for property accesses. `x[6]` retrieves a property with the name `"6"` on `x`, and TypeScript does not restrict the use of bracketed property accesses on non-arrays.